# Как написать что данные введены не правильно, и чтобы ошибка не выдавалась

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хотел написать программу которая взаимодействует с модулем brawlstats и **прога запрашивает тег игрока в игре после чего пишется сколько у него кубков**. Ну вот задача если я напишу *неправильный тегом игрока*, то тогда в консоле напишется ошибка и прога закроется, а нужна чтобы писалась что тег введен неверно.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def mess(message):
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip()
    player = client.get_profile(get_message_bot)
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Имя профиля: {player.name}\nТвои кубки: {player.trophies}\nМакс. кубков: {player.highest_trophies}", parse_mode="html")

    except Exception as E:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вы ввели не правильно свой тег")
```

Пример с правильным тегом:
Введите свой тег: 28gqvqjqy --> У вас 28100 кубков\

Пример с не правильным тегом:
Введите свой тег: dwawadzx --> raise NotFoundError(404, invalid_chars=invalid)
brawlstats.errors.NotFoundError: An incorrect tag has been passed.Invalid characters: D, W, A, W, A, D, Z, X\

**я хочу чтобы код писал при не правильным тегом писал что тег не правильно написан**. Хотя я думаю что заместо ответа я получу -1 как всегда, но если вы ответьте на мой вопрос то я буду сильно благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
try:
    player = client.get_profile(input("Введите свой тег"))
    print(player.trophies)
except Exception as E:
    print(E)  # Если нужна ошибка
    print('Неверно набран тег')  # Если нужно вывести определенный текст
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! о такой вещи как try я не знал

Comment: Если вы хотите работать с подобного рода функциями, вам это необходимо изучить)

Comment: а у меня вопрос я вот хотел это все интерпетировать в телеграм бот но при написание правильного тега то пишет "неверно набран тег"

Comment: давай код, без него ничего не пойму, скорее всего)

Comment: а как отправить? слишком огромный

Comment: отредактируй код в вопросе

Comment: сделал чекай ради тебя

Comment: попробуй занести player = ... в try

Comment: пытался не работает, НО проблема была в том что я водил тег игрока который не состоит не в одном клубе из-за этого он и писал ошибку, Теперь он работает спасибо тебе за помочь!!!))

Comment: да, не за что))

Comment: Очевидно, что это плохой пример. Что будет, если там другая ошибка?

Comment: except Exception словит вообще все ошибки, если нужно отлавливать разные ошибки, то надо смотреть, какие ошибки вообще могут быть и отлавливать уже каждую. Вообще не понял, к чему вы это написали